# No. Transactions 0

Tags: blockchain, e-wallet

Dears,

I just have sent my BTC to my wallet on crypto naptor and I see via blockchain.info tool the following:

No. Transactions 0
Total Received 0 BTC
Final Balance 0 BTC

I sent my BTC from eobot system to my wallet 1Ny9RuXuBJYRZs8jfRZ1PABkyc5435mRs2 :

Confirmation about sending please see below:

12/15/2017 1:45:21 AM PT WITHDRAW BTC 0.02845822 to 1Ny9RuXuBJYRZs8jfRZ1PABkyc5435mRs2 TXID c675182bab90695ccb88cf9fef23e67104e03a7433a13cc9354a997318c461da

Please advice why the balance as well as transaction number is 0 and why BTC hasn't been delivered yet.

Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction does not appear to exist on the network. Either Eobot has not broadcast the transaction yet, or it was unconfirmed for a while and forgotten by the network. In either case, you should contact Eobot as they are the only ones who can resolve this issue for you.

Comment: Andrew thanks for answer. I already sent two mails to eobot but no answer so far :(